# How to pass a subroutine as a parameter to another subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I want to pass a subroutine as a parameter to another subroutine.

Subroutine `question` should be passed as parameter to subroutine `answer`? How can I do it with Perl?

```
question();

sub question {
    print "question the term";
    return();
}

sub answer() {
    print "subroutine question is used as parameters";
    return();
}
```

Comment: You don't need parenthesis after `return`.  More importantly, note that `return;` (without anything)  in fact returns `undef`.  If you want to indicate that all went well -- which is always a very good idea -- you normally do `return 1;`.

Comment: @zdim only in scalar context

Comment: @ysth Yes, good point, thank you.  In list context it's a different game, in this sense.

Comment: Also remove the parens after "sub answer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take subroutine reference using `\&subname` syntax and then, you can easily pass it to other subroutine as arguments like a scalar. This is documented in [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lexical-Subroutines) and [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References). Later you can dereference it using [`Arrow operator(->)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator).

```
sub question {
    print "question the term";
    return 1;
}

my $question_subref = \&question;
answer($question_subref); 

sub answer {
    my $question_subref = shift;
    print "subroutine question is used as parameters";
    # call it using arrow operator if needed
    $question_subref -> ();
    return 1;
}
```

Or you can create an anonymous subroutine by not naming it. It may lead to interesting case of [`closures`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)

```
my $question = sub  {
                        print "question the term";
                        return 1;
                     };
answer($question);

# you can call it using arrow operator later.
$question -> ();
```

Comment: If i have another subroutine named as question1(now i want to pass question and question1 subroutine inside subroutine answer how can pass it)

Comment: Take reference of question1 like question i.e.  `my $question1_subref = \&question1;` and pass it to sub `answer`.

Comment: *"It may lead to interesting case of closures"* That is irrelevant and out of context. There is no closure here.