# In Perl, pass a parameter into a subroutine which is also a parameter

Tags: perl

So my question is based off of this SO question:
[How to pass a subroutine as a parameter to another subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169771/how-to-pass-a-subroutine-as-a-parameter-to-another-subroutine)

Question is: can I pass arguments/parameters into the subroutine (which is also itself a parameter)?

```
sub question {
print "question the term";
return 1;
}

my $question_subref = \&question;
answer($question_subref); 

sub answer {
    my $question_subref = shift;
    print "subroutine question is used as parameters";
    # call it using arrow operator if needed
    $question_subref -> ($PassSomethingHere,$SomethingElse);
    return 1;
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

$question_subref -> (**$PassSomethingHere,$SomethingElse**);

---

Heres the actual code:

```
my $SelectResults = sub {
            my @results;
            $sql = $_[0];
            $sth = $_[1];
            $sql =~ s/select/SELECT/gi;
            if(StrContains($sql, "SELECT"))
            {
                @results= $sth->fetchrow_array();
                foreach my $tab (@results) {
                    print $tab . "\n";
                }
            }
            return @results;
        };



sub MySQLExe
{
    my @results;

    my $db = "fake";
    my $usr = "user";
    my $pw = "password";

    $db_handle = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=$db;mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;", $usr, $pw) \
        or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr \n";
    my $sql = $_[0];
    print $sql . "\n";



    #Prepare SQL query
    my $sth = $db_handle->prepare($sql)
        or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql': $DBI::errstr\n";



    $sth->execute
        or die "Couldn't execute query '$sql': $DBI::errstr\n";


    # I can't seem to get this to work...   
    # optional Function here - get rows from select statement or something else.
    # pass in the function holder as the second parameter
    my $Func = $_[1];
    @results = $Func -> ($sql, $sth);


    #disconnect  from database
    $sth->finish;
    $db_handle->disconnect or warn "Disconnection error: $DBI::errstr \n";


    return(@results);
}
```

And Actual usage:

```
my @tables = MySQLExe("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='$table';", 
    $SelectResults);
```

Comment: The actual application is to pass in **JUST what changes** into a dbi->mysql subroutine.  I want all the connection opening and closing stuff to always be the same and never change.  But I want my sql statement AND a function which returns an array (sometimes) of results.  It'd be handy if the function could do different stuff depending on the application, but I can't seem to find a way around it.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Injection bug!!! `"SELECT ... WHERE table_schema='$table';"` should be `"SELECT ... WHERE table_schema=".$dbh->quote($table)`

Comment: @Ed., Best not to hide the error at all so it can addressed.

Comment: Your code mixes a lot of different styles, especially in naming variables and functions. It looks like you have not written it yourself, but either inherited and edited or copy/pasted it together from several sources. Are you sure you know what you are trying to accomplish? Can you explain why you want to do it in this way? It seems overly complicated. We can probably help you find a much simpler way if you explain what problem you are ultimately trying so solve.

Comment: Thanks - yeah that's an injection error, thx.
I am new to perl and it shows, yes it's cobbled together from what I could find online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted in an answer to the linked question, what you're probably after is a [closure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3F) (see also [Perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/pub/2002/05/29/closure.html), [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))):

```
sub make_questioner {
  my ($text) = @_;
  return sub {
    my ($politeness) = @_;
    print $text, $politeness, "\n";
    my $answer = <>;
    chomp $answer;
    $answer;
  };
}

my $questioner = make_questioner("What... is your name");

my $name = $questioner->(', please');
print "Your name is '$name'.\n";
```

You'll note that the demo code here incorporates information passed on creating the closure, and also uses a parameter passed to the closure.

Comment: Let's have the OP walk before they run?

Comment: I still don't understand what they are trying to do. when I read the title of the question, I immediately thought _curry_, but I think that's not really what they want. The code is such a mess, I'm just now going through it. You might want to include a wiki link to closure too. That might be easier to understand than the refcount stuff in Perl.

Comment: Good idea. Will use perlfaq7 answer instead of the perlref bit.

Comment: @simbabque  Exactly the same here -- but then I read their comment right below the question and thought "closure."  I completely agree that a nice and down-to-earth explanation would be helpful (to help them walk).

Comment: Thanks, yes a closure is what I'm looking for.